# I am making a program in java on loops and encountered an error

Tags: java, loops, bluej

The program is as follows...

```
 public class SDD
 {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int x=0, y=10;

        do{

            ++x;

            y-=x++;

        }while(x<=7);
        return(y);
    }
}
```

The error is as follows......

Cannot return a value from method whose type is void.

Comment: well, you can´t return from a `void` method...

Comment: which function is calling main method. main is void. you can't return value. it's java not c or c++.

Comment: But what should I do to be able to compile it and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class SDD
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
          int x=0, y=10;   
          do{    
             ++x;    
             y-=x++;

           }while(x<=7);
          System.out.println(y);
        }
   }
```

Comment: Code only answers are a no-no. Please add some explanation!

Comment: still you need explaination. it's straight forward. main is always void so you can't return value. main is starting point so, all outputs are came here.

Answer (score 0):

Your main method is declared as void, so it cannot return a value. The last line (return y) is trying to return the value of y. This is not allowed.

If you want to display the content of y, you could replace that line with:

System.out.println("y = " + y);

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line .

```
 return(y);
```

Add this line :

```
System.out.println("y = " + y);
```

or you can rewrite the program as follows :

```
public class SDD
 {
    public static int main(String args[])
    {
        int x=0, y=10;

        do{

            ++x;

            y-=x++;

        }while(x<=7);
        return(y);
    }
}
```